# App flicks or twinkles at some point on android 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, flicker

I have spent long time on this, this is driving me craze.

My app works all fine on `android 4.1` and below. But it have a big problem running on `android 4.2.2`

At some point the app just start a endless flicking or twinkling, until it eat up all memory of the phone, then the phone died.

I have no idea where this problem is triggered, i don't know which line of code cause this strange problem. Because it has not bad log at all, it runs from `onCreate` to the final line of `onResume` and its all fine, but after that it just jumped in to `onDestroy` automatically, then run into `onCreate` again, it's an endless loop.

During the loops, all logs i have got is like this:

```
11-26 16:48:56.497    1491-1491/com.efergy.module W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-26 16:48:56.545    1491-1491/com.efergy.module D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 212K, 47% free 18253K/34312K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 6ms
11-26 16:48:56.549    1491-1491/com.efergy.module D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 47% free 18251K/34312K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 6ms
11-26 16:48:56.565    1491-1491/com.efergy.module D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 259K, 47% free 18505K/34312K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 4ms
11-26 16:48:56.593    1491-1491/com.efergy.module W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-26 16:48:56.649    1491-1491/com.efergy.module D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 269K, 47% free 18253K/34312K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 6ms
11-26 16:48:56.661    1491-1491/com.efergy.module D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 47% free 18251K/34312K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 7ms
11-26 16:48:56.673    1491-1491/com.efergy.module D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 244K, 47% free 18448K/34312K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 7ms
11-26 16:48:56.705    1491-1491/com.efergy.module W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-26 16:48:56.753    1491-1491/com.efergy.module D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 213K, 47% free 18254K/34312K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 5ms
11-26 16:48:56.761    1491-1491/com.efergy.module D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 47% free 18251K/34312K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 7ms
11-26 16:48:56.773    1491-1491/com.efergy.module D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 259K, 47% free 18505K/34312K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 5ms
11-26 16:48:56.793    1491-1491/com.efergy.module W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Any words or recommendations to help me find out where the problem is are appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your code related to this activity is not huge please post it, or cut the method and post only onresume() ondestroy etc

Comment: I am sorry, because there are lots code together with self-define functions in there. but this problem didn't happened just in one activity but other activities. So i was thinking about if it is related to the global things.

Comment: how doe sit works on 4.3? can you find if it is because of an API limit (okay below 4.1, failed above) or because of the phone itself (are you on emulator? can you try with 2 different manufacturers?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this problem by myself.

In my case, it caused by the abuse of

```
updateConfiguration()
```

i use it to manage language in each activity inside

```
onConfigurationChanged()
```

Once the change of the orientation triggered the  `onConfigurationChanged()`, inside it will call `updateConfiguration()` which will trigger `onConfigurationChanged()` again, that will running into an endless loop.

So carefully review your use of these two functions, you will find something.